# How to exit c sub-programs inside of python program, without exiting python

Tags: python, c, loops, exit

I have a python program, which loads c program using `CFFI`. The python program makes a loop executing the c program many times. However a `exit(0)` was used in c under a certain condition. So once the `exit(0)` in C is executing, the python terminated it self as well. But what I try to achieve is, in case c program was executed and exited by `exit(0)` or even normally terminated, python program should continue to run. Anyone has an idea how to do that other than multiprocessing? Or can `exit(0)` be substituted with other code? Thanks a lot.

python.py:

```
ffi = FFI()
lib = ffi.dlopen("mylib.so")
ffi.cdef ("int function1(int my_value);")

mylib_value = 10;
mylib_value = ffi.cast('int', my_value)
for i in range(10):
    lib.function1(mylib_value)
```

mylib.c:

```
int function1(int mylib_value):
    ...

    if(certain condition)
        exit(0);
    else
        continue...
    ...
```

The code are something like above. Inside the loop, when `i=0`, c executes `exit(0)`, and then the python program exits as well. Where I want the c exits without python existing, so that it will keep running following loops.

Comment: Could you update your answer to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: @jpnadas yes, of course

Comment: Sorry mate, can you please elaborate your python code a bit more? That is not very reproducible as it stands.

Comment: @jpnadas The code were really nothing else than that, I added more detail, maybe that would help?

Comment: In your python code, how is `ffi` initialized? or is `ffi` simply an alias to the `CFFI` module? How is `lib` initialized?

Comment: @jpnadas Ah, sorry, I didn't realize you meant the `ffi` part. I revised it.

Comment: no worries. It is still missing the definition of `mylib` and `my_value` though.

Comment: @jpnadas `my_lib` is actually `my_lib.so`, where it is compiled by `my_lib.c`. The code works well, but I cannot figure out  how to terminate c only, without terminate python.

Comment: Are you sure you can run that code with `my_lib.so` without even a quotation mark?

Comment: @jpnadas oh, sorry, I forgot the quotation mark. Also, the `mylib_value` was just a random integer.

Comment: I got that much. I finally managed to reproduce your problem. I will see if I can help you now.

Comment: @jpnadas yeah, I haven't explained it well I guess :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for you to do it is to return something from within your function and deal with that in your python code.

For instance:

```
# main.py
import cffi


ffi = cffi.FFI()
lib = ffi.dlopen('my_lib.so')


ffi.cdef("int function1(int my_value);")


for i in range(10):
    print(f"testing my function with value: {i}")

    mylib_value = ffi.cast('int', i)
    ret_value = lib.function1(mylib_value)
    if ret_value == -1:
        print("c code exited before completing")
    else:
        print("c code exited normally")
```

```
// main.c
int function1(int my_value) {
    if (my_value == 1)
        return -1;

    // My code here

    return my_value;
}
```

Running `exit(0)` will indeed terminate your python execution.

Comment: But I have one more question, if a structure instead of a integer should be returned from C, in this case, how can I free the memory of this structure? Is it fine without releasing it?

Comment: You do not manage memory yourself in Python, so you don't have to do anything. Also, you only need to free memory in C if you dynamically allocate it.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I almost forgot python manages the memory itself. Thanks a lot^^